# Firestore: Query by item and get different documents and render it on react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I have a collection "users" which has multiple documents corresponding to each user. In each user there is property "locationName" which is of array type and can contain multiple location names(2-3 max). eg locationName : ["chicago","boston","seattle"].

In my case, when somebody enters a locationName in input field in react client i should be able to fetch all documents(user) data which have that location in their array.

As this is backend logic, i can use cloud function to get all user|document id. But how to pass down that information to Redux Store so that only relevant doc is shown??

One way i though is dump all doc id found (in cloud function) in a new collection ("doc selected") meaning updating firestore and then connect with the collection through redux firestore but in my case multiple request might be coming so that will cause system overflow?

Is this possible through firestore?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to read all user documents where the `locationName` array contains for example `chicago`? If so, you can do that directly from the client with an `array-contains` query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership.

Comment: i got your point but let's say there as 1K user in firestore. Will not pulling all these object to client and doing array-contains logic be heavy on client side of stack.Suppose only 1 out of 1K matches criteria is it not feasible to pass down 1 result than 1K through firebase connect and redux state.?

Comment: The `array-contains` operator is executed on the server.

Comment: Ok, lets say through cloud function using Array-contains i am able to get all doc(user) satisfying the condition. But how will i pass those object only to client for rendering . Currently i have a container component where i am using firestore connect () to sync it props from firestore collection("users") where i am getting all doc(user) . I am completely new to firebase and react, please ignore if i say something technically wrong.

Comment: Ok you meant using array-contains at client side that runs on server and fetches the relevant documents?